# I have problem with links in my magento store

Tags: magento-1.9, link

I am having problem with my magento store. My links are not working properly...

My page links are like

for CMS pages

`localhost/about-us`

`localhost/contact-us`

and for category page

`localhost/my-category`

for product page

`localhost/my-category/my-product`

now problem is... when I try to redirect from `localhost/my-category/my-product` this link to Another cms page it suppose to redirect to `localhost/about-us` this, But it is actually redirecting to `localhost/my-category/about-us`

where will be the problem?It is only happening with CMS pages

Comment: From where are you adding links to your website? I mean from admin panel or from any file?

Comment: I am using Mega menu plugin for it. it automatically gets links

Comment: Means you are putting only "about-us", "contact-us" etc. as links in menu from admin panel?

Comment: Yes correct. I am using only links which i gave it in the CMS page setting

Comment: Now when i go to product-page all pages links gets that product category name in the link

Comment: Can you share screenshot of how are you managing menu link items in admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

First you get the url of cms page

```
$url= Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('url_key');
```

Then try below code to redirect

```
$this->_redirect($url)

OR

Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```